# combine 2 query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 sql requests

1. select name,id from table
2. select name,place from table

How to group by name 2 sql query?
result:

```
name, id, place
```

Comment: `select name, id, place from table`?

Comment: @ScottHunter perhaps that should have been placed as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select every Column from `table` just use:

```
select * from table
```

alternate:

```
select name, id, place from table
```

If the 2 tables are not the same join them like @Lukas Gabsi already suggested:

```
select a.name, a.id, b.place from table a 
   join table b 
      on a.name=b.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

is it the same table? 
else i would try to join if the name is unique

```
select a.name, a.id, b.place from table a 
   join table b 
      on a.name=b.name;
```